# Errors and warnings into a file?

Tags: php, apache, logging

Example: I create a Smart-search project, I would wish that come in `error.log` (in the root of my project).

How can I activate only PHP errors in each project which I create?

Comment: Any errors will be written to a log file already. If you use apache, by default that is at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I know but I want to change the chemein

Answer (score 1):

For each project you could set a specific error log using `ini_set()` in your project config file:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/project/root/error.log");
```